# redundant systemd-journal-remote for systemd-journal-upload instances

Tags: debian, systemd, logs, systemd-journald, journalctl

I'm using **systemd-journal-upload** on serveral nodes to forward their journals to a single **systemd-journal-remote** sink, *loghost01*:

```
/var/log/journal
├── <foo-bar>
│   ├── system.journal
│   └── user-1000.journal
└── remote
    ├── remote-x.x.x.x.journal
    └── ...
```

This worked out the box for me on Debian 9 and systemd 232.

But I would like to have a redundant system, say *loghost02*, which works as a second **systemd-journal-remote** instance that also receives the uploaded journals.

Unfortunately, adding another URL to `/etc/systemd/journal-upload.conf` (on the uploading nodes) does not work:

```
[Upload]
URL=http://<REMOTE_IP_01>:<REMOTE_PORT>  # this is ignored
URL=http://<REMOTE_IP_02>:<REMOTE_PORT>  # this is working

# enable HTTPS
...
```

The [config docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journal-upload.conf.d.html) are silent on this issue.

How would I achieve redundancy in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You can run one or more instances interactively with:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journal-upload \
--url=https://my.server.domain \
--key=path_to_key.key \
--cert=path_to_cert.crt \
--trust=path_to_trust.crt \
--save-state=/var/tmp/state.my.server.domain
```

and change the url, ssl info or state file as you need for each. Since you can do this, you can also make your own unit files for them and not use the default setup. All you did in your example is redefine URL before starting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to achieve redundancy on the receiving end, by using a web service with redundant infrastructure to receive the logs.